# Laurent expansion of $f(x)=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

> I am trying to find the Laurent  expansion of $f(x)=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)^2}$ when $0<|z-1|<1$.

I thought that if 
\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{z-2}+\frac{1}{(z-2)^2} \\
&=\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{2-z}+\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{2-z}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{1-(z-1)}+\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{1-(z-1)}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{z-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z-1)^n+\frac{d}{dz}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z-1)^n\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{z-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left((z-1)^n+n(z-1)^{n-1}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{z-1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z-1)^n\left(1+n(z-1)^{-1}\right) \\
\end{align}
But this does not agree with the series generated by wolfram. What about this method is incorrect?

**alternative approach suggested by David**

\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{1}{z-1}\left(\frac{1}{(z-2)^2}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{z-1}\frac{d}{dz}\left(-\frac{1}{z-2}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{z-1}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{1-(z-1)}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{z-1}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(z-1)^n\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{z-1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(z-1)^{n-1}\right) \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(z-1)^{n-2}
\end{align}

Comment: Just because something disagrees with Wolfie, it doesn't make it wrong. Wolfie is not the ultimate arbiter in mathematics. I presume that $n$ should be $k$ in the above....

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. You are completely right. But without any written solutions, it is hard to verify my answers. Either I am wrong, or wolfie is.

Comment: You've added a better one!

Comment: is it correct? :)

Comment: now is better!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In line 2, $-\frac{d}{dz}$ should be $+\frac{d}{dz}$.
2. Your final sum has many powers duplicated and these could be collected into single terms.  For example when $n=5$ the first term is $(z-1)^5$ and when $n=6$ the second term is $6(z-1)^5$.
3. Easier method: take $\frac1{z-1}$ as a multiplicative factor at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was very helpful. I have added the (far easier) method that you suggested. Is it correct?

Comment: Looks right to me.  Note that the $n=0$ term contributes nothing to the sum and could be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one: let $z-1=w$ to make it easier then with $0<|w|<1$
$$\dfrac{1}{1-w}=\sum_{n\geq0}^\infty w^n$$
differentiating shows
$$\dfrac{1}{(1-w)^2}=\sum_{n\geq1}^\infty nw^{n-1}$$
therefore
$$\dfrac{1}{w(w-1)^2}=\sum_{n\geq1}^\infty nw^{n-2}$$

Comment: Nice method. I shall use this substitution from now on